# ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=22003 on java select from DB2

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, bigdecimal

i'm having the following exception with this method, any guess?
The same exception is thrown even if i change the parameters of the function, i also tried with String but the problem is the same.

```
public void getDettagliLottoPerPersonalizzazione(BigDecimal numeroLotto, BigDecimal progressivoApparato, BigDecimal numeroScatola) throws Exception
    {   
        List<DettaglioLottoPersonalizzazioneDTO> dettaglioLottoResult = null;
        Query query = null; 
        try
        {
            logger.info("Ricerca dettaglio lotto da personalizzare per numero lotto " + String.valueOf(numeroLotto) );                          
            XmlQueryReader prop = XmlQueryReader.getIstance();
            String queryDettaglioLotto = prop.getQuery(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "queryLetturaDatiPerPersonalizzazione");                    
            query = entityManagerView.createNativeQuery(queryDettaglioLotto);
            query.setParameter(1,numeroLotto);
            query.setParameter(2,numeroLotto);
            query.setParameter(3,numeroLotto);
            List<Object[]> result =  query.getResultList();
            for (Object[] objects: result) {
                System.out.println((String)objects[0]);
                System.out.println((String)objects[1]);
                System.out.println((String)objects[2]);
                System.out.println((String)objects[3]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception  e)
        {
            logger.error("Errore durante la ricerca del dettaglio lotto da personalizzare per numero lotto "  + String.valueOf(numeroLotto) + ". " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("Errore durante la ricerca del dettaglio lotto da personalizzare per numero lotto "  + String.valueOf(numeroLotto));
        }
        logger.info("Ricerca dettaglio da personalizzare numero " + String.valueOf(numeroLotto) + " avvenuta con successo");
    }
```

Here's the exception

```
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse 

Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: [jcc][t4][1037][11190][4.19.49] An exception occurred during BigDecimal conversion.  Refer to the attached Throwable for more details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=22003
Error Code: -4220
Call: 
        SELECT a.D_ORD AS data_ordine, a.C_FOR||a.C_OBU_NEW AS codice_apparato, b.C_POS AS postazione_personalizzazione, c.T_ID_POS AS identificativo_postazione
        FROM EVDA.TETS3T_INT_SRV A
        INNER JOIN EVDA.TETSKI_INT_CON_ORD B ON a.C_CTP_CLI = b.C_CTP_CLI AND a.D_ORD = b.D_ORD
        INNER JOIN evda.TETSIL_POS_PER C ON b.C_POS = c.C_POS 
        WHERE b.N_LOT_PRD = ?
        AND a.N_PRG_TIT_PRE = ?
        AND b.N_SCA = ?


bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="
        SELECT a.D_ORD AS data_ordine, a.C_FOR||a.C_OBU_NEW AS codice_apparato, b.C_POS AS postazione_personalizzazione, c.T_ID_POS AS identificativo_postazione
        FROM EVDA.TETS3T_INT_SRV A
        INNER JOIN EVDA.TETSKI_INT_CON_ORD B ON a.C_CTP_CLI = b.C_CTP_CLI AND a.D_ORD = b.D_ORD
        INNER JOIN evda.TETSIL_POS_PER C ON b.C_POS = c.C_POS 
        WHERE b.N_LOT_PRD = ?
        AND a.N_PRG_TIT_PRE = ?
        AND b.N_SCA = ?
    ")
```

The same query executed on DBeaver works fine.

Comment: "An exception occurred during BigDecimal conversion". You are forcing a cast to String always (in each System.out.println).

Comment: The code throws exception on List<Object[]> result =  query.getResultList();

Comment: You are using a very old db2jcc.jar.  Your db2jcc4.jar is 4.19.49 version (dating from Db2 v10.5 fixpack 7).   Most likely the dbbeaver is using a more recent driver.  Upgrade your db2jcc4.jar driver to version 4.31.10 or higher, get this download from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads.

Comment: Sadly I can't, the client want to use this jar, so i can't update

Comment: Fix the code to also collect the "attached throwable", which may give more details of the exception, and may suggest which cast or other workaround may be appropriate. We cannot see your data, your column-data-types and which parameter value triggers the exception.   Refusing to maintain antique drivers always is more costly than keeping drivers up to date.

Comment: You use three times `BigDecimal numeroLotto` as query parameter, `BigDecimal progressivoApparato` and `BigDecimal numeroScatola` are not used, and I guess one of them as to be a `String`

Comment: Seems to me that you are not using plain JDBC, but an unknown library [to me] to connect to the database, as per the `Query` class there. I would suggest you get support on the use of that library.